# Zenject - install generic binding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, zenject

Good day.

I have an interface:

```csharp
public interface IRepository<T>
{
   //Stuff
}
```

and an implementation:

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
   //Stuff implementation
}
```

now I would like to bind it all together in a container.

I found Zenject to be somewhat similar no Ninject synthax-wise so I tried the following:

```
public class IoC : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
         Container.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
    }
}
```

This throws an exception when I try to validate the scene (Edit -> Zenject -> Validate Current Scenes):

```
Assert hit! Invalid type given during bind command.  
Expected type 'Assets.Sources.Core.Infrastructure.Repository`1[T]' to derive from
type 'IRepository`1'
```

So I suspect this is just an incorrect way to do generic bindings. I wonder what the right one is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with Zenject, which should be fixed now as of today.  You should now be able to bind abstract open generic types to concrete open generic types, like in your example.

Can you try updating from the master branch of the [github repo](https://github.com/modesttree/zenject) ?